# Change background for View inside RecyclerView item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Inside my recyclerView, I have items that contain the date and other item information about an item in a layout.
The problem is that when I try to change the background color, not for all item, but only for some of its content, I have a bug that changes the background of other items.

I need to change the background for part of the item layout except for the date.

**This code works, but changes the background color for all item:**
[image: gif]

```
    public void setItemContent(ReminderModel model, ArrayList<ReminderModel> reminders, int position) {
        if (position > 0) {
            ReminderModel previousReminder = reminders.get(position - 1);
            LocalDate previousDate = previousReminder.getDateTime().toLocalDate();
            LocalDate currentDate = model.getDateTime().toLocalDate();

            if (previousDate.compareTo(currentDate) == 0) {
                date.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        if (position == 0) {
            date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        this.reminderId = model.getId();

        final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yy");
        final DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
        String dateString = dateFormatter.format(model.getDateTime());
        String timeString = timeFormatter.format(model.getDateTime());

        title.setText(model.getTitle());
        description.setText(model.getDescription());
        date.setText(dateString);
        time.setText(timeString);

        if (model.isSelected()) {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(itemView.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blue));
        } else {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(itemView.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        }
    }
```

This code changes background color as I need, but there is a bug, changing background color for other items, regardless I don't even touch them. [image: gif]

```
    public void setItemContent(ReminderModel model, ArrayList<ReminderModel> reminders, int position) {
        if (position > 0) {
            ReminderModel previousReminder = reminders.get(position - 1);
            LocalDate previousDate = previousReminder.getDateTime().toLocalDate();
            LocalDate currentDate = model.getDateTime().toLocalDate();

            if (previousDate.compareTo(currentDate) == 0) {
                date.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        if (position == 0) {
            date.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        this.reminderId = model.getId();

        final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yy");
        final DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
        String dateString = dateFormatter.format(model.getDateTime());
        String timeString = timeFormatter.format(model.getDateTime());

        title.setText(model.getTitle());
        description.setText(model.getDescription());
        date.setText(dateString);
        time.setText(timeString);

        if (model.isSelected()) {
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.container_reminder).setBackgroundColor(itemView.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blue));
        } else {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(itemView.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        }
    }
```

**The only difference is in this line:**

```
itemView.findViewById(R.id.container_reminder).setBackgroundColor(itemView.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_blue));
```

where R.id.container_reminder is a part of the item's layout, I need to change the background.

***item layout***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/view_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/image_date_background"
        android:backgroundTint="#2C6991"
        android:fontFamily="@font/andika"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="DATE" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_reminder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/view_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/andika"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="TITLE" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/view_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:fontFamily="@font/andika"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                tools:text="TIME" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/view_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/andika"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="DESCRIPTION" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please share the xml of the row item layout

Comment: I added item layout